# eCommerce Site - CC Expiery Year Date?

Tags: ecommerce, creditcard

I have an eCommerce Site and I am building the payment form. I have a dropdown list for the user to enter the year, how many years in advance should I program? I obviously start with 2013 and go up but how far in advanced should I program? 10 years? I do not want to have to few but also not to many. How far in advance is common?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no official guideline as the credit card issuers can choose each when the cards they issue will expire. In fact they have been issuing cards for longer and longer periods of time. If you're trying to determine how far out into the future you should accommodate expiration dates for, err on the safe side and give your customers many years to choose from. That way you future proof your application.

Answer (score 2):

I just went on Amazon and looked at the form to add a credit card to my account.  They have 25 years in their drop down (from 2013 through 2037).  I would recommend doing the same thing the other major retailers are doing.